# Shiny reactive dropdown misbehaving (with number inputs)

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, shiny-reactivity

This is a mockup of a summary block that shows the Top or Bottom 10 of a value that is being plotted elsewhere.

**ISSUE**

Changing the variable name or sort direction is working fine, but changing the limit (`limit1`) of how much data to show, works initially showing 10 but changing it to less like 5 ends up showing all the data. Changing to higher values sometimes works but not always. It is very weird!

So OK

[image: Deafult app on startup]

Not OK

[image: App when choose 5]

**CODE**

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

dataset1 <- as.data.table(iris)

server <- function(input, output) {
# Top table
  datatop1 <- reactive({

    dt <- copy(dataset1)
    setorderv(dt,input$t1, input$sort1) # -1 is descending

    # choose subset of rows  
    row.limit <- min(nrow(dataset1), input$limit1) 
    dt <- dt[1:row.limit, ]

    # choose columns  
    dt <- dt[, .(Species, get(input$t1))]
    setnames(dt,"V2",input$t1)

    return(dt)
  })

  output$top1 <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(dataset1)) {

      fluidRow(inputPanel(
        selectInput("limit1", "Limit:", 
                    c("5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "50"),
                    selected = "10"),
        selectInput(("t1"), "Variable:", choices = names(dataset1),
                    selected = "Sepal.Length"),
        selectInput("sort1", "Sort by:", 
                    choices = c('Bottom / Asc.' =  +1 , 'Top / Desc.' = -1),
                    selected = -1)
      ))
    } 
   })


  # Top panel
  output$screenTop1 <- renderTable({    
    # top dataset is in reactive as function
    datatop1()
  })
  output$screenTop <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      uiOutput("top1"),
      uiOutput("screenTop1")
    )
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(tabPanel("Top", uiOutput("screenTop"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Is it a problem with the subsetting of the `data.table`? Or the way I am using reactive? Shiny experts - I would appreciate a steer on what I am doing wrong,  and why as I have not fully grasped reactivity yet.  Apologies the code is a bit convoluted as the main code is inside a different file structure.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6 shiny_0.13.2
```

**EDIT: Explanation**

@Pork Chop's great comments below explains that `min` can end up coercing all to character. So when faced with 226 and "5" it became a test of "226 " and "5" and on an element by element basis "2" beats "5" so "226" was chosen as minimum and all rows where shown.

But for 10 and 20 it was not e.g. "226" and "10" first digit 1<2. And correct minimum was shown. *Lesson: watch type and make sure you set SelectInput input$vars to `as.numeric` when needed.*

Mystery explained!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your subset with:

`row.limit <- min(nrow(dataset1), as.numeric(input$limit1))`

**Edit:**

1) As `min` needs a `numeric` variable to compute the `min` properly you need to `cast` to correct data type: `as.numeric(input$limit1)`, otherwise it will take the other numeric variables

2) By default the `selectinput` is of type `string`, as `selectInput()` and `selectizeInput()` use the `JavaScript` library [selectize.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js)

3) If you read [selectize documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) you will find that `"Selectize is instantiated from a <input type="text"> element"`

Going forward in your development I would suggest you to use `validate` and `need` as much as possible, you can find some documentation [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html). Also try to use `print` as much as you can

**To clarify taking a min of character strings:**

If you type `?min` you will find that for character string the evaluation is follows:

- If a **one** string is present in the collection it will coerce the entire set to type `character`
- When taking `min` the sorting for character strings is done using [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), meaning the alphabetical order, this means that if you take `min(c("10",2))`, it will return `"10"` as `1` comes before `2` once `2` is `coerced` into the character string

Comment: Thanks Pork Chop that worked a treat. Please can you **explain why** in your answer as this has been driving me mad for a half a day. Do you always need to check type on your input variables?  When do you need to?

Comment: Thanks PorkChop for the extras and tips. i used `print` and was surprised to see it keep coming back with 226 as min from time to time. Weird how the string gets converted some of the time and did not always wig out.

Comment: Note that most of the great programmers pay attention to datatypes a lot more than anything else

Comment: So true- I should know better I grew up with basic! Been spoilt by R's lazy evaluation. Thanks once again

Comment: @PorkChop Can you also explain this correct behavior compared to the behavior seen by the questioner: `min(c("1",2))`. And on the min-help page you find this: ... == numeric or character arguments (see Note).

Comment: @PorkChop Thank you very mutch. I missed this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# choose subset of rows  
  #row.limit <- min(nrow(dataset1), input$limit1) 
  dt <- dt[1:input$limit1, ]
```

It's not neccessary to "calculate" the `row.limit`. As its a number you can directly include it. It's like `dt[1:5, ]`

Comment: I was worried about the data recycling if the data loaded is smaller than the rows chosen. i.e. dataset has 33 items and you choose view 50? You end up with blanks below. Any idea why do changes in `input$limit1` not recalc the `row.limit` and choose all instead?